# open command prompt window and change current working directory

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm terribly new to scripting on windows. Using windows 7 64.

I'm trying to make a .bat file that I can double click, and have it open a command prompt and automatically `cd` me to a certain directory.

I tried making a .bat file with

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd "cd C:\my\destination"
```

Which opens what looks like a command prompt, but doesn't seem to let me type any commands.

I then tried:

```
@ECHO OFF
start cmd "cd C:\my\destination"
```

But this just sent me into a loop opening tons and tons of prompts until my computer crashed :) The .bat file was located in the destination directory if that matters.

Comment: The reason your first `bat` file won't let you type is because the process has finished.

Comment: @Ardman, the first .bat file worked correctly without the /k flag, once I renamed the file to something besides `cmd.bat`

Comment: btw, people interested in my question may also find this useful: in windows explorer, hold the shift key and then right click - you'll see a new option, "open command prompt here", which is awesome sauce.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd.exe /K "cd C:\my\destination && C:"
```

The quoted string is actually two commands (separated by a double ampersand): The first command is to change to the specified directory, the second command is to change to the specified drive letter.

Put this in a batch (.BAT) file and when you execute it you should see a Command Prompt window at the specified directory.

Comment: Or `cd /d C:\my\destination` – changes drive and directory in one go.

Comment: Saved me a crap ton of looking by finding this. This is great for Salesforce developers using ANT

Answer (score 11):

Use the **/K** switch:

```
@ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe /K "cd C:\my\destination"
```

But IMHO, the most useful switch is **/?**.

```
Starts a new instance of the Windows XP command interpreter

CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
/S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K (see below)
/Q      Turns echo off
...
```

And only if it does not work, then Google it, as @Neeraj suggested :D

Comment: This works. It turns out the /k flag wasn't needed. The reason my previous attempts failed and sent me into a loop was because I had named my .bat file cmd.bat, and I used cmd instead of cmd.exe(thank you google)

Comment: I had the same problem. I also named my batch file as cmd.bat and that's the loop cause. The /k option is not needed to solve this issue. That's why I voted up @chris comment.

Answer (score 5):

This could be done like that:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd /D "C:\my\destination"
cmd.exe
```

If you need to execute a file or command after you open the cmd you can just replace the last line with:

```
cmd.exe /k myCommand
```

Comment: I was wondering about the cmd /K situation where you'd need to nest quotes for long paths.  While there is likely an easy way to handle that, this negated that issue implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

```
@ECHO OFF
%comspec% /K "cd /D d:\somefolder"
```

The /D will change folder **and** drive and works on 2000+ (Not sure about NT4)

If you take a look at Vista's open command here, it uses `cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\"` but I don't think %V is documented. Using pushd is a good idea if your path is UNC (`\\server\share\folder`) To get UNC current directory working, you might have to set the [DisableUNCCheck](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156276) registry entry...

Comment: +1 for the /d. I use the /d all the time too.  It is simpler ! .  start cmd.exe /K "cd /d C:\my\destination"

Answer (score 2):

Why so complicated? Just create an alias to cmd.exe, right click on the alias and navigate to its settings. Change the "execute in" to the path you want to have as standard path. It will always start in this path.

Comment: Whoa now you're making things WAY too easy ;-) Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

just open a text editor and type

```
start cmd.exe

cd C:\desired path
```

Then save it as a .bat file. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch file *"go-to-folder.bat"* with the following statements:

```
rem changes the current directory
cd "C:\my\destination"
rem changes the drive if necessary
c:
rem runs CMD
cmd
```