# How to open the command prompt from a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

For quick access to the command prompt pointing to a specific directory, I would like to double click on a .bat file (saved on the desktop), and then the command prompt will open pointing to a specific folder, and would like the command prompt to remain open.
This is what I did:

```
rem -changing the drive to e:
e: 
rem - setting the path to the specific folder
cd \users\myName\Documents\folderName\folderName\folderName\
```

==> this results on the command prompt opening in the specify directory, but closing right away.

I have no problem opening in the 'e' drive (start cmd e: ), but when I specify the path to the folder, it does not work

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This question is off-topic here and has been already answered on  superuser http://superuser.com/questions/586967/leave-cmd-windows-open-called-from-batch-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the option /K of the cmd.exe

Please take a look at the following link:

[open command prompt window and change current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717352/open-command-prompt-window-and-change-current-working-directory)

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for: 
cmd.exe /K "E: && cd E:\users\Laura\Documents\folder\folder\folder"

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
cd /d "e:\users\myName\Documents\folderName\folderName\folderName\"
cmd /k
exit
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It didn't do what I was expecting.

Comment: Probably because of the extra shell.  Try it with the exit command I added above.  It opens a CMD prompt in the folder you choose.

Answer (score 0):

The /K option is the key, as has been said.  However, if you want a better CMD environment, considering creating shortcuts to CMD in a desktop folder.  By changing the properties of each shortcut, you can then customize the environment, window size, fonts, buffers, etc.

To do this, create a shortcut with a Target something like this:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /K C:\Batch\your_batch_file.bat
```

In your_batch_file.bat, you can set environment variables, paths, select the drive, set the working directory, etc.

By changing the properties of the shortcut, you can totally customize the window size, fonts, colors, buffers, etc.

I use this to set up separate environments for Ruby, JRuby, CMD, etc.

The shortcut properties looks something like [image: this]:

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work for me like that, but it gave me the idea: In the properties window 'Shortcut' tab; I set target only setting the drive 'E', and in the 'Start in' box, I set the path to the specific folder. Thanks! Laura

Comment: Surely.  This was just a screenshot of what I use.  YMMV.  Thanks.