# How to open a command prompt through a batch file in a specific directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file

If we open a Command Prompt it will come like

```
"C:\Users\......> "
```

Then I am doing `cd "D:\Proj\sfk\net\"`

To go "D:\Proj\sfk\net\"> Then from there i am executing commands say commands.

If i have batch file , On click of that it should open automatically with that path then it will be easier..

I tried

```
START cmd /K "D:\Proj\sfk\net\"

START cmd.exe -- "cd D:\Proj\sfk\net\"
```

It's not working..

How to Achieve that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [open command prompt window and change current working directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717352/open-command-prompt-window-and-change-current-working-directory)

Comment: Search [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/) there are tons of answers to your question. You will have varieties of answers that best meets your need to choose from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this at the top of the batch file :

```
cd /d %~dp0
```

It will change to the directory where the batch file resides.

If you must do it without touching the batch file, then start it like this :

```
cmd /k "cd /d d:\temp & mybat.bat"
```